# How to check duplicates in vector of structs using map c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, count, duplicates

I need to count duplicates and i'm trying to count duplicates using map.
I've been trying but the problem is I keep having error as follows :

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    dup[*it]++;
}
```

And this is my code:

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `p = new ChildInfo[childNum]; std::vector<ChildInfo> v(p, p+childNum);` ? Why not simply `std::vector<ChildInfo> v(childNum)` ?

Comment: Does `ChildInfo` implement `operator <` (for `std::map`) ?

Comment: Wouldn't `std::vector <ChildInfo> v (p, p+childNum);` create copies in `v`, so updating `p` in the loop later has no effect on it? Its a vector of `ChildInfo` objects, not pointers to `ChildInfo` objects.

Comment: @Jarod42 How to implement operator < in ChildInfo?

Comment: `bool operator < (const ChildInfo& lhs, const ChildInfo& rhs) { return lhs.gram < rhs.gram; }` seems what you want (`id` ignored for the map), but then a functor seems more appropriate for semantic.

Comment: @Jarod42 Omgg it works! Thanks a lot but I still dont understand why I add that one

Comment: `std::map` relies (by default) to `operator <` to compare its keys.